# Index of split line

Tags: python, split

I have an input file as:

```
.......  
.......  
# Start  
A 2 100  
B 3 200  
C 4 1000  

# End  
........
........
```

I would like to print column 2 as:

```
2  
3  
4
```

my code is:

```
with open("my_file.txt") as f:  
     parsing=False  
     for line in f:  
        if line.startswith("# Start"):  
            parsing = True  
        elif line.startswith("# End"):  
            parsing = False  
        if parsing:  
            line = line.split()  
            if line:  
               print line[1]
```

However, I get an output error as

```
print line[1]  
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I use print line[0], it prints:

```
A  
B  
C
```

Any suggestion where I went wrong

Comment: Use a diff variable name and change your condition to `out = line.split();  if out and len(out) > 1:`

Comment: Have tried printing what `line` is?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hi Thanks it works!!!!

Comment: @shanu: that's no solution as long as you don't know, why there is a line, that has only one element

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks, now I figured it out. The line below #Start contains dashes. That's why it was giving error

Answer (score 3):

check the `length`/`size` of `line` [after `line.split()`] before accessing the second element in the array [`line[1]`]

Try;

```
with open("my_file.txt") as f:   
    parsing=False  
    for line in f:  
        if line.startswith("# Start"):  
            parsing=True  
        elif line.startswith("# End"):  
            parsing=False  
        if parsing:  
            line_arr = line.split()  
            if len(line_arr) > 1:  
                print line_arr[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, you have also to ignore dash-lines:

```
with open("my_file.txt") as f:  
    parsing = False  
    for line in f:  
        if line.startswith("# Start"):  
            parsing = True
        elif line.startswith("# End"):  
            parsing = False  
        elif line.startswith("---"):  
            pass # ignore these lines 
        elif parsing:  
            line = line.split()  
            if line:
                print line[1]
```